# Why is this MessageDialog freezing?

Tags: python, wxpython

A  `wx.MessageDialog` freezes up my entire UI when shown, only the mouse pointer moves, nothing on my screen is clickable. I have to kill the process from a terminal.

This happens for all dialogs like color picker or a yes/no. But not for a file selector.

Details of threads: there happens to be a `CallLater` which happens in **another** frame.

Here is the offending piece and the offending line:

```
def append_data_point(self, data):
c, l, r = data
if not self._spectrum_data.data_present:
    print "hey no data"
    dlg = wx.MessageDialog(
    parent  = self, 
    message = "data not loaded, create a new data",
    caption = "no data loaded" ,
    style   = wx.OK)
    print "created dialog"
    dlg.ShowModal()
    print "showed modal" #THIS NEVER RUNS
    dlg.Destroy()
```

Above function happens to be bound to a certain button:

```
 self.btn_open_file.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.open_file)
```

---

Selecting a file (from OS interface, of course) works:

```
def open_file(self, event):
    dlg = wx.FileDialog(
        parent   = self, 
        message  = "select a spectrum file", 
        wildcard = "*.spectrum", 
        style    = wx.OPEN)
    if dlg.ShowModal() == wx.ID_OK: #PERDECTLY OK
        chosen_file = dlg.GetFilename()
        chosen_dir  = dlg.GetDirectory()
        filepath    = os.path.join(chosen_dir, chosen_file)
```

Comment: I have a stupid question. Does the application still hang after you hit the OK button on the dialog?

Comment: When the dialog shows, nothing on my screen is clickable for any reasonable time.

Comment: Who is "self" in the code? A wx.Frame?

Comment: A `wx.MessageDialog` of course. It happened to be a threading problem that somehow froze any dialogs

Comment: All wx-code should be run from the same thread. You can have multiple threads, but everything wx related has to go to the wx-thread. Use `wx.CallAfter` or `wx.CallLater` to do the communication.